# Sencha 2.2 - Where can I download draw and chart package from?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have downloaded sencha 2.2 and building an application which uses the shapes and text tools to display data and other information. I tried to use Ext.draw and Ext.chart functionality but wasn't able to run them.

The problem is that I am not having any of the files in my senchatouch/src/draw and senchatouch/src/chart folder. How can I get these files so that I can proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using the free commercial version which doesn't include the charts. If you want to use the charts, you should use the open source version which includes charts with a mark on them. If you want charts without the mark you should buy a license which is included in one of the sencha bundles.